# Cannot use variable with Get-User -Filter in Exchange Management Console

Tags: powershell, console, exchange-server

I cannot seem to use variable in the situation below.

```
[PS] C:\>Get-User -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "Test.Smith"}
Name                                                        RecipientType
----                                                        -------------
Test Smith                                                  UserMailbox

[PS] C:\>$SamAccountName = "Test.Smith"
[PS] C:\>Get-User -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName}
[PS] C:\>echo $SamAccountName
Test.Smith
[PS] C:\>
```

You can see the command works fine when I type out the name, but not when I use a variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to this cmdlet, are you sure it takes a scriptblock and not a string?  If it takes a string try this:

```
Get-User -Filter "SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName"
```

If it really takes a scriptblock try:

```
Get-User -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName}.GetNewClosure()
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. I am not sure which it takes, but the quote method generated an error, and the {}.GetNewClosure() made no difference. I copied this line from Step 5 here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb936719%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx#NewUsrps1

Comment: The docs say it is supposed to take a string - go figure.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996896(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Example two from those docs: `Get-User -Filter "Title -like '*Manager'"`.  Try `"SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccountName'"`.

Comment: Ah! That's it! I needed the single quotes. The correct command is     get-user -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samAccountName'"   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the comments, add single quotes around the variables, or your filter result has incorrect syntax.

```
 Get-User -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccountName'"
```

When passing parameters directly you can just pass the variable. But in this case you are building a properly formatted query string, and the single quotes are part of that.

When you get a full answer, don't leave it as a comment... create it as a full answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Or see the comments in the accepted answer.